# Flask `app.before_request` when using a factory function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

the docs suggest using factory function.

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    return app()
```

so I don't have access to my app when I'm writing my code, 
for this porpuse there is an object called " current_app " in flask module, 
so I did this and I got " out of application context error "

```
@current_app.before_request
def before_req():
    whatever...
```

how can I define before request functions when I'm using a factory function?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your before_request function inside `create_app` function:

```py
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.before_request
    def before_request(response):
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        return response

    return app
```

If you use Flask Blueprints, you define `before_request` function for your blueprint like this:

```py
from Flask import Blueprint

my_blueprint = Blueprint('my_blueprint', __name__)

@my_blueprint.before_request
def before_request(response):
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    return response
```